# I am able to invoke an Azure Function, but I don't receive any response

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I have followed this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-java) to create an Azure function in VS Code using Java and Maven.

the code is the following:
[image]

```java
    public class Function {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using the "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
     * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
     */
    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);
        context.getLogger().info("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOo");

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
        } else {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, 2" + name).build();
        }
    }
}
```

the host.json is the following:

[image: host.json]

the local.settings.json is the following:

[image: local.settings.json]

then I am able to start the Azure function locally with:

mvn azure-functions:run -f "c:\Users\francesco.di.rienzo\Desktop\Azure f1\pom.xml".

and the output in the terminal is the following:

```
Functions:

HttpExample: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.

[2023-05-02T16:09:12.497Z] Worker process started and initialized.

[2023-05-02T16:09:15.362Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F10D2648'.
```

but when I copy that link in the browser I don't see anything, the page just keeps loading, but in the terminal, in VS Code, I can see that there is a new log:

```
Executing 'Functions.HttpExample' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5aadbadf-3198-4532-8fdb-f704637233b3)
```

and that's it.

When I run mvn test -f "c:\Users\francesco.di.rienzo\Desktop\Azure f1\pom.xml" I can see in the terminal that those two loggers are printed:

```
context.getLogger().info("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOo");
context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
```

I have tried also using IntelliJ, with the same code, but I have the same

I tried calling the Azure function that I created following the link, but I didn't receive any response even if it seems that the function started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your requirement in command line by following [MSdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?tabs=cmd,azure-cli,browser) and could achieve expected results.

You can achieve the same in VSCode by running the below commands after creating a Java Azure function:

```
mvn clean install
mvn azure-functions:run
```

*Creating a Java Azure function:*

[image]

**Function Code:**

```cs
@FunctionName("HttpExample")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req",
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
                
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    // Parse query parameter
    final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
    final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);
        
    context.getLogger().info("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOo");
    if (name == null) {
       return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
    } else {
      return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
    }
}
```

`mvn clean install` let's Maven `clean` all the previously compiled .class files and resources in each module and build the project from the clean state before running the `install` phase for each module.

[image]
[image]
[image]
Run `mvn azure-functions:run`
[image]

**Response:**

when I run function URL, I could see the expect output in console.
[image]

**Browser:**

[image]